# What is causing this error message?

Tags: java

Heres my code the comments summarizes what the program is suppose to do.

```java
// This program will read in from a file a number that tells how many
// wages and hours worked the file contain. And then calculates the
// salary
import java.util.*;
import java.text.*;

public class Lab10
{
        public static void main(String[] args)
        {
          // Declare variables
          Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);
          DecimalFormat fmt = new DecimalFormat("0.00");
          String name;
          double wages;
          double hoursWorked;
          double salary;
          int numCalculate;
          int EmployeeNumber ;
          int i = 0 ;

          // Read in how many employees the file contains
          EmployeeNumber =scan.nextInt() ;

          // for loop that reads and records the name hoursworked and wages , and prints out the information
          for ( ; i < EmployeeNumber +1; i ++ )
          {
           name = scan.next () ;
           wages = scan.nextDouble() ;
           hoursWorked = scan.nextDouble() ;

           salary = calculateSalary(wages,hoursWorked) ;
           System.out.println(name +" worked " +fmt.format(hoursWorked) + " with a wage of " + "$" +fmt.format(wages) + " and got paid $" +fmt.format(salary) );
          }
          // End of control loop

         } // End of main method

         public static double calculateSalary(double wages, double hoursWorked)
         {
//Declare constants
          final int OVERTIME_BREAK = 40;
          final double OVERTIME_MULTIPLE = 1.5;
          double salary = 0 ;

          //Calculate salary

          if(hoursWorked > OVERTIME_BREAK)
          {
          salary = (hoursWorked - OVERTIME_BREAK) * wages * OVERTIME_MULTIPLE + hoursWorked * wages;
          }
          else
          {
            salary = hoursWorked * wages;
          }
          // Return the salary
           return salary ;

         } // end of calculateSalary method
} // End of Lab10 class
```

When using this input file:

```
3
Smith 12.50 25
Jones 25.89 60
Brown 7.86 19.89
```

I get my desired output but this message tacked on the end:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.util.NoSuchElementException
    at java.util.Scanner.throwFor(Scanner.java:855)
    at java.util.Scanner.next(Scanner.java:1364)
    at Lab10.main(Lab10.java:32)
```

Could someone please tell me what this means and how to fix it?

Answer (score 2):

You are looping one too many times.

You have 3 employees and should therefor just loop like this:

```
for ( ; i < EmployeeNumber; i ++ )
{
    name = scan.next () ;
    ...
 }
```

Comment: thats it , thank you.  it works now

Answer (score 0):

Java's array indexing starts with 0, So if you have 3 elements those are stored at 0, 1, and 2. As, said above in your for loop, if you just put i < EmplyeeNumber is sufficient, not EmployeeNumber + 1.